# Create and add a Marathon application

Tags: nginx, docker, mesos

I am new to mesos and now i am trying to execute the [Part 1: Creating a Public App](https://docs.mesosphere.com/getting-started/tutorials/deploywebapp/) on my windows system. I've created the `nginx.json` and then run the command:

```
dcos marathon app add nginx.json
```

I'm getting the error like

```
Error decoding response from [http://ec2-(...).amazonaws.com/marathon/v2/info]:
HTTP 404: Not Found
```

below is my folder structure:

```
Directory: C:\users\rams\dcos\simple-docker-tutorial
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---         1/13/2016   1:59 PM         64 Dockerfile
-a---         1/13/2016   1:57 PM         79 index.html
-a---         1/13/2016   5:26 PM        398 nginx.json
```

can you help to solve the error where i am doing wrong thanks in advance...

Comment: What is the output of `dcos marathon app list`?

Comment: PS C:\Users\rams\dcos\simple-docker-tutorial> dcos marathon app list
Error decoding response from [http://ec2-54-200-172-175.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/marathon/v2/info]: HTTP 404: Not Found

Comment: Have you followed https://docs.mesosphere.com/installing/ Looks like there's no Marathon below that endpoint...